# Nginx static website subpath as parameter

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have the following problem that I cannot manage to find a solution.
I added a subdomain in nginx that I want to serve a static html file. The problem is that, on this subdomain, I need to rewrite all path variables as query parameters in the html that is served by reverse proxy.
I tried a lot of config combinations but none is working.
My config is:

```
server {

    server_name status.mywebsite.com;

    location ~ /(.*) {
            try_files $uri /html/file/location/my-html?id=$1 =404;
    }
```

}

What I need to achive is that when a user is accessing `https://status.mywebsite.com/22` to serve `/html/file/location/my-html?id=22`.

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Actually, the html page to be served is /html/file/location/my-html.html?id=22 . I forgot to add the .html extension in the question.

Comment: How exactly does your HTML file use the query argument passed to it? Is it some kind of application?

Comment: Basically `root /path`

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, it is using javascript to get the query parameter.

Comment: "I need to rewrite all path variables as query parameters in the html that is served by reverse proxy." - do you mean that you want to rewrite the contents of the HTML file that is sent by nginx?